# Groovy XML parsing: Content is not allowed

Tags: xml, groovy

i am trying to parse some Text out of a XML"Construct" within a database field. I allready googled and read that it might be the problem, that i don't really have a "valid" XML and it might be a BOM problem, but there is no way to change the XML within the database, so somehow i have to parse it.

This is my XML (I want just the Amount):

```
<Prices><Price Qty="1" FromDate="2015-04-30"><Amount>10.43</Amount></Price></Prices>
```

This is my groovyscript:

```
def parser = new XmlParser(false,false).parseText("item.Prices")
def t = parser.Amount."$Input".text()
```

(Where i later want to use the t for an output in a line like this:

```
    def line = item.ItemId + "\t" + item.FAMId + "\t" + t + "\t" + item.FAMId +  "\t"+status )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you already have the XML text pulled out of the database and stored in a groovy variable? Your script so far only shows that you are trying to parse the string `"item.Prices"` as an XML string, which will fail. If you need to get the data from the database, that is a different question.

Comment: Sorry, the problem seems to be, that the content i define as "item.Prices" is a string, not a text, but i don't seem able to change that :|

Answer (score 0):

My problem just was using the xmlparser for a string instead of using the xmlslurper.
This code works:

```
def preis = item.Prices_ShopCOM
def parser = new XmlSlurper(false,false,true).parseText(preis)
def t = parser.Price[0].Amount[0].text()
```

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You're calling the wrong method on "XmlParser".  The "parseText()" method expects to receive the string to parse.  You should use the "parse(File)" method, and you'll have to create a File object from the file name.

It helps to have the Groovy javadoc available, so you don't make simple mistakes like this.

Comment: the OP says, that he has the XML in a DB, so no file here

Comment: Ah. Perhaps the OP meant "item.Prices" to be without quotes? Can't tell for sure from this.

Comment: When i use it without quotes i get a NullPointerException :/
item.prices is the Field within the Database (or at least meant to be) which contains the xml

Comment: Ah, well, then I'd say your problems have nothing to do with XML parsing.  Make sure that you've got your XML to be parsed in a variable.

Comment: You seem to be right, if i put a XML string directly into the script it runs, but the definition def preis = "item.Prices_ShopCOM" won't run. `def preis = "item.Prices_ShopCOM"

def parser = new XmlParser(false,false).parseText("preis")
def t = parser.Price[0].Amount[0].text()`

Comment: Sorry, `def preis = item.Prices_Shop_COM` without the " "